# How to open custom file type (.abc) with a custom program (abc_viewer)?

Tags: macos

I have a custom file type (just a fancy csv file), with extension `.abc`

I then have a c++ program (some opengl and basic gui stuff) that renders the data in `.abc` files, this program is called `abc_viewer`. This program is built using cmake, not a Cocoa or xcode based project.

How can I make it so when I double click on a `.abc` file it opens with `abc_viewer`?

I have tried adding `abc_viewer` to Applications, and also tried "Open With" on `.abc` files, but every time `abc_viewer` is greyed out and wont let me select it as an option.

Im on Ventura 13.3.1.

Comment: Since no one has added anything here, yet, I’ll throw out an idea. I’ve never built an app with Cmake, or even Xcode, but I have definitely built “apps” using a tool called Platypus.  They’re really just wrappers around a script that you provide, in my case, usually a Perl script, but it can also be a shell script. You could make a platypus app that just launches your ABC viewer app (passing along any command line arguments), and then associate your ABC files with the platypus-based app. I can double click on M3U files to open my platypus app, which runs my perl-based script, should work 4 u 2